# Restrict creation of children forms using generics in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, generic-programming

After testing for a bit, I came up with the following solution to avoid (from the MdiParent Form) the creation of more than one instance of children forms.

For the first form, the code came up as:

```
public CatForm MyCatForm {
    get {
        var myCatForms = 
            MdiChildren.Where(form => form.GetType() == typeof(CatForm));

        if (myCatForms.Count() > 0)
            return (CatForm)myCatForms.First();

        return new CatForm { MdiParent = this };
    }
}
```

So far so good, now I was going to start repeating myself with the other children forms (please just change the word Cat to Dog, Sheep) and you will know what I mean.

Could somebody please write a piece of code that works similar to:

```
private Form GetForm<T>(T form){
    var myForms = MdiChildren.Where(aForm => aForm.GetType() == typeof(T));

    if (myForms.Count() > 0)
        return myForms.First();

        return new (typeof(T) as Form) { MdiParent = this } ;
}
```

It seems that C# in compile time is unable to determine the returning type :(

Would reflection be a proper approach to follow in this case?

I would like to be able to create a unique instance of any children form.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need constraints on this:

```
private Form GetForm<T>(T form) where T: Form, new()
{
    var myForms = MdiChildren.Where(aForm => aForm.GetType() == typeof(T));

    if (myForms.Any())
        return myForms.First();

    return new T() { MdiParent = this } ;
}
```

This constrains the method to only work with `Form` types (allowing you to set `MdiParent`) and uses a `new()` constraint so the constructor works.

Comment: +1 for the .Any() (heaps better than the old fashioned Count() plus the comparison) and using constraints with methods (I have used them only with classes). Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are into oneliners, try this:

```
private Form GetForm<T>(T form) where T: Form, new()
{
    return MdiChildren.OfType<T>().SingleOrDefault()
        ?? new T() { MdiParent = this };
}
```

The OfType LINQ operator does the same as Where(e => e is T).